# How to convert MediaStream from MP4File

Tags: javascript, video, webrtc, filereader, mediastreamsource

I making VideoStream with peer.js in webRTC.But Mediacall cann't send that File object.only MediaStream.Please ask that How to convert MediaStream to MP4File.

```
          var file = this.files[0];//.mp4 Data
          var mediastream = new window.webkitMediaStream(file)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can stream mp4 easily using adobe flash with the satandard player build on it

and with zero code

'just import the file using wizard and have fun'

[see this below:](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/learn-flash-professional-cc/importing-audio-and-video-into-flash-professional/)